# WP CLI allowed fields?

Tags: wp-cli

Very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer.

I am using the WP CLI post get command: https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/get/

One of the option is [--field=], but I can't find in the doc the list of allowed values for this field.

What am I missing?

Comment: Note that you need `--fields=`, not --field, and they can be comma separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of fields is available on the [`wp post list`](https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/list/#available-fields) page.

> These fields will be displayed by default for each post:
>
> ```
> ID
> post_title
> post_name
> post_date
> post_status
> ```
>
> These fields are optionally available:
>
> ```
> post_author
> post_date_gmt
> post_content
> post_excerpt
> comment_status
> ping_status
> post_password
> to_ping
> pinged
> post_modified
> post_modified_gmt
> post_content_filtered
> post_parent
> guid
> menu_order
> post_type
> post_mime_type
> comment_count
> filter
> url
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think you have not see example section or the example section is available now.

If you want to display only one field then you can use `--field` parameter.

E.g

```
wp post list --field=ID
```

And to get multiple fields then you can use `--fields` parameter.

E.g.

```
wp post list --fields=post_title,post_status
```

`--field` is associated argument. Read more about the associate arguments at https://wp.me/p4Ams0-1g1